# Guzzle : Send JSON using PUT method

Tags: json, laravel, put, guzzle

I want to update a Group so I use the put method to send json p.e. {"admin":1,"user":0}.

```
$response = $this->_client->put("http://10.10.10.10.xip.io/groups/29")->send();
```

I've tried to add it to the url but with no luck. I can't seem to grab it in my back-end.
Keep in mind i'm using Laravel for the back. Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: You don't seem to add json to the request. see https://guzzle3.readthedocs.org/http-client/request.html#put-requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guzzle :

```
$this->_client
     ->put($this->_requestUrl, array(), json_encode($this->_restObject))
     ->send();
```

Laravel

```
Input::json()->all()
```